# Cannot find 'ChildNodes' in System.Xml.Linq.XNode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

following code is being compiled correctly on .Net framwork 4.5.

```
  public void SetProperties(System.Xml.XmlNode properties)
        {
                int tempFor1 = properties.ChildNodes.Count;
        }
```

As type `System.Xml.XmlNode` is obsolete now in `.NetCore` so I replaced it with `System.Xml.Linq.XNode`.
But when I try to build it on .NetCore It gives error of "ChildNodes" Not found.

Here is the updated code.

```
public void SetProperties(System.Xml.Linq.XNode properties)
        {
                int tempFor1 = properties.ChildNodes.Count;
        }
```

What is the possible solution to get count of child nodes?

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this...

```
public void SetProperties(System.Xml.Linq.XNode properties)
{
     var element = properties as XElement;
     int tempFor1 = 0;
     if (element != null)
     {
        tempFor1 = element.Elements().Count();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your XNode is an Element, then cast it to an XElement. It will then have an Elements() method which you can Count() using standard Linq to Objects. If you don't see the Count() function, make sure to add

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: There is not Elements property instead a function with same name. and it does not have Count function

Comment: Correct - it's a function. But the good news is, the function with no arguments returns the full collection, and you can Count() that.